# Sprite between a certain range

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game where a 'cloned' sprite spawns every 3 seconds using the 'InvokeRepeating' method. Once the sprite is spawned it is spawned at an exact location using:

```
spike.transform.position = new Vector3 (0f, 11f, 0f);
```

How would get the sprite to be spawned between a certain range e.g. between X: -2 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the "[Space Shooter tutorial - Spawning Waves](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/spawning-waves?playlist=17147)" they show this exact process in video form.

Use [`Random.Range(float min, float max)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) that will give you the inclucive range from min to max.

```
spike.transform.position = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-x, x), 11f, 0f);
```

Then you can set `x` to `2` or any other range value you need.

Comment: Sorry @JoeBlow I'm new to this. I will remember next time! 

Comment: OK buddy ... you rock.  As you can imagine you get some people on here who are not helpful like that.  If possible please "tick" the other questions you have got answers to, thanks a lot.